# Can't find value in whole array in JSON value

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Postgresql 9.6

json:

```
 "availability": [
      {
        "qty": 25,
        "price": 3599,
        "is_available": true
      },
      {
        "qty": 72,
        "price": 3599,
        },
         "is_available": true
   ]
```

Suppose I want to search in first array's item. I use this query:

```
SELECT product.data #>'{availability, 0, price}' from product
```

OK.
But I need to find in whole array (all array's items).

I need smt like this (pseudo code

```
SELECT product.data #>'{availability, *, price}' from product
```

Is it possible?

Comment: That's not a "full text search".

Comment: As I have commented before. If you want to make things easier, you need to upgrade to Postgres 12, where you can use JSON/Path expression which allow you to do that. You won't be able to do that with the somewhat dated version 9.6

Comment: So what is the output you want? An array with all price values in the embedded array?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name output must be empty array if not find price, or original json if find price in any array's (availability) items

Answer (score 1):

> *output must be empty array if not find price, or original json if find price in any*

Sounds like a strange requirement, but the following would do that.

```
select case 
           when (select jsonb_agg(e.item -> 'price') 
                 from jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'availability')  as e(item)
                 where e.item ? 'price') <> '[]' then data
           else '[]'::jsonb
       end
from product
```

A simple array with the prices makes more sense in my opinion:

```
select (select jsonb_agg(e.item -> 'price') 
        from jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'availability')  as e(item)
        where e.item ? 'price') as prices
from product
```

Comment: Is it possible to return result as  tsvector  type?